# Laravel : how to call method in model from controller

Tags: php, laravel

I have model tracking and method getTarcking with return is response from API, i want call those response from controller and parsing to view

I my controller create index method

```
$Mrespone = $this->Tracking->getTracking();

return view('tracking/index'['respon'=>$Mrespone]);
```

But, In controller I got error

Comment: Can you add more code please.

Comment: Also, provide the error that you get.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a comma(,). Try dd($Mrespone) just to be sure whether you are getting a response or not.

```
$Mrespone = $this->Tracking->getTracking();

return view('tracking/index',['respon'=>$Mrespone]);
```

Answer (score 0):

first debug whether you getTracking() is getting response or not.

`dd($Mrespone)`

if data is showing then comment dd() and for view you can do like this

```
return view('tracking/index')->with('respon', $Mrespone);
```